# JSF setPropertyActionListener setting javascript integer value

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

In JSF2 i want to set some integer value.

For example:

> `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{aBean.aValue}" value="2" />`

How can i set integer value from javascript command:

> PrimeFaces.widgets["widgerVarValue"].paginator.getCurrentPage()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function setHiddenValue(new_value){

        document.getElementById('myForm:hidden2').value = new_value;

       }
    </script>

<h:form id="myForm">            
   <h:inputHidden id="hidden2" value="#{user.hidden2}" />
</h:form>
```

**See also:**

- http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-new-hidden-value-to-backing-bean-in-jsf/